# Write on sdcard permission android +6

Tags: android, permissions

I want to write on sdcard (External sdcard) on android +6.

When I use this runtime permission:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

It just works for internal storage but on sdcard i get:

`java.io.IOException: Permission denied`

How can other apps write on sdcard?

Thanks.

Comment: Use the Storage Access Framework (e.g., `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved
1. in android +6 the Runtime Permissions just work for Device Storage and not for Sd Card (External SD)

2.For External SD you must Use SAF (Storage Access Framwork) and select sdCard Directory

via this Code you can run SAF (Storage Access Framwork)

`startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE), 42);`

[image]

After select the sdcrd directory the onActivityResult method was run

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultData) {

    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK)
        return;
    else {
        Uri treeUri = resultData.getData();
        DocumentFile pickedDir = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, treeUri);
        grantUriPermission(getPackageName(), treeUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(treeUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);


        preferences = getSharedPreferences("MyShared" , MODE_PRIVATE) ;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit() ;
        editor.putString("Dir" , treeUri.toString());
        editor.commit() ;



    }
}
```

the SAF return intent of selected Directory

and we get intent data as a Intent treeUri

(Very Important)→→ for  write on sd card in android 6+ you must use From DocumentFile instead of File

and DocumentFile get sd card Directory

Dont Forget to save treeUri in the SharedPreferences , Because you need to save the Directory of Sd Card  and every time you need can get it from SharedPreferences

and now pickedDir is the Sdcard directory , you can use it

Answer (score 0):

For API 23 and above, you need to explicitly request permission from the user AND include the uses permission tag in your android manifest: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Not Works , It just works for internal storage ; i want SdCard (External SdCard)

Answer (score -1):

### USE this library to get permission in android phone

https://github.com/nabinbhandari/Android-Permissions

### Also see this link you get possible information for the solution

[Storage permission error in Marshmallow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162152/storage-permission-error-in-marshmallow)

Comment: Not Works on SdCard ;

Comment: By default you need to provide the path in start. of your Sd card directory